# Turtle Graphics program no output

Tags: c, linux

As the title says i'm creating a turtle graphics program that will take commands from a file (01_A.txt) and use those to move around a turtle in a 40x40 area, drawing '*' on the ground when the pen is down. My program so far I believe is receiving the inputs from the file, yet I get no output. Any assistance would be great!

```
/* PROGRAM:  turtle_A.c
AUTHOR: Taylor Havart-Labrecque
DATE:27/02/16
TOPIC:
PURPOSE:  Simple Turtle Graphic
LEVEL OF DIFFICULTY: HARD
CHALLENGES:
HOURS SPENT:
NOTES:


*/
/**************************************************************************/
/* Declare include files
 **************************************************************************/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
/**************************************************************************/
/* Defines
 **************************************************************************/
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0
#define MAX 100
#define SIZE 40

#define RIGHT 0
#define DOWN  1
#define LEFT  2
#define UP    3
#define TOTAL_DIR 3

/**************************************************************************
 Function Prototypes
 **************************************************************************/
int readCommands( char c[] );
int execCommands( char c[], int n );
int turnRight( int d );
int turnLeft( int d );
void moveTurtle( int down, int a[][ SIZE ], int dir, int dist);
void printFloor( int a[][ SIZE ], char c);
int x = 0, y = 0;

/**************************************************************************
 Main
 Read commands from stdin or file
 Execute the commands
 **************************************************************************/
int main( void ) {
/* Array for commands, set to the maximum amount. */
    char commands[MAX] = {0};
/* Number of commands, used to decrement the switch statement*/
    int ncmds;
    ncmds = readCommands(commands);
    execCommands(commands, ncmds);

    return 0;
}

/**************************************************************************
 readCommands
Read one command at a time and store it in the commands arrays
 Reads until the EOF ( CTL-D ) or the MAX maximum number of commands is
 reached

 ARGUMENTS:
   commands:  An empty array of chars to store the commands read
               commands is modified in this function

 RETURN:
    number of commands read
 **************************************************************************/
int readCommands( char commands[]) {
int i=0;
int counter = 0;
char command;

FILE* file = fopen("01_A.txt", "r");
fscanf(file,"%c", &command);
while(!feof(file)){
    fscanf(file,"%c", &command);
    for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++){
        counter++;
            commands[i]= command;
    }
}
return counter+1;
}
/**************************************************************************
 execCommands
 execute one command at a time
 ARGUMENTS:
    commands:  an array containing valid turtle commands
    ncmds   :  number of commands stored in commands
              0 <= ncmds < MAX
 **************************************************************************/
int execCommands( char commands[], int ncmds ) {

    int i = 0;
    char cmd;
    int dir = 0;
    int floor[ SIZE ][ SIZE ] = { { 0 } };
    int penDown = FALSE;

    cmd = commands[i];

    while ( ncmds-- ) {
        switch ( cmd ) {
        case 'U':
            penDown = FALSE;
            break;
        case 'D':
            penDown = TRUE;
            break;
        case 'R':
            dir = turnRight( dir );
            break;
        case 'L':
            dir = turnLeft( dir );
            break;
        case 'F':
        moveTurtle( penDown, floor, dir, 1 );
        break;
    case 'P':
        printFloor(floor, '*');
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    cmd = commands[i++];
}
return 0;
}
/**************************************************************************
 turnRight
 Turn the turtle direction to the right ( 90 degrees counterclockwise )
 **************************************************************************/
int turnRight( int d ) {

    if (d == RIGHT){
    d=DOWN;
}
else if(d == DOWN){
    d=LEFT;
}
else if(d == LEFT){
    d = UP;
}
else if(d == UP){
    d = RIGHT;
}
else
    printf("Can not turn right!(Boundary Reached)");
return d;
}


/**************************************************************************
 turnLeft
 Turn the turtle direction to the left ( 90 degrees counterclockwise )

 *************************************************************************/
int turnLeft( int d ) {
if (d == RIGHT){
    d = UP;
}
else if(d == DOWN){
    d = LEFT;
}
else if(d == LEFT){
    d = UP;
}
else if(d == UP){
    d = RIGHT;
}
else
    printf("Can not turn left!(Boundary reached)");
return d;
}

/**************************************************************************
 movePen
 move the turtle a distance dis in the direction dir from current pos
 if the pen is
 down, place a 1 in floor position
 ARGUMENTS:
    a   :  floor
    down:  1 if pen is down
    dir :  direction turtle is facing
    dist:  How far to walk
 *************************************************************************/
void moveTurtle( int down, int a[][ SIZE ], int dir, int dist) {
int i;

if (down == TRUE && dir == RIGHT){
    for (i = 0; i < dist; i++)
    {
        a[x][y+i]=1;
    }
    y+=(dist);
}
else if(down == TRUE && dir == LEFT){
    for (i = 0; i < dist; i++){
        a[x][y-i] = 1;
    }
    y-=(dist);
}
else if (down == TRUE && dir == UP){
    for (i = 0; i < dist; i++){
        a[x-i][y] = 1;
    }
    x-=(dist);
}
else if(down == TRUE && dir == DOWN){
    for (i = 0; i < dist; i++){
        a[x+i][y] = 1;
    }
    x-=(dist);
}
else if (down == FALSE && dir == RIGHT){
    y+=(dist+1);
}
else if (down == FALSE && dir == LEFT){
    y-=(dist-1);
}
else if (down == FALSE && dir == UP){
    x-=(dist-1);
}
else{
    x+=(dist-1);
}
return;
}

/**************************************************************************
 printFloor
 Print the floor
 ARGUMENTS:
    a   :  floor
    c   :  char to use to print the floor
 *************************************************************************/
void printFloor( int a[][ SIZE ], char c){

int i,j;

for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
    printf("\n");
    for (j = 0; j < SIZE; j++){
        if (a[i][j] == 1){
            printf("%c", c);
        }
        else{
            printf(" ");
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: TL;DR. See [ask] and provide a [mcve]. stack overflow is no debugging service.

Comment: when calling the function: `fopen()`,  always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Comment: when calling the function: `fscanf()` always check the returned value (in the current scenario it should always be =1) to assure the operation was successful

Comment: the function `feof()` will not perform as the code is expecting.  strongly suggest using the call to `fscanf()` in the while() statement for loop control.

Comment: this loop: beginning with `for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++){` should be replace with: `commands[counter] = command;`

Comment: Would it be better if I used something like `while((c = getchar())!= EOF)` for the while loop? I realize that feof is the wrong approach now, oversight on my part. Thanks for your help!

Comment: the functions: `turnRight()` and `turnLeft()` are complete nonsence.  Suggest giving them a complete re-design  As  hint, a turn operation is a turtle movement.   and the boundaries of the 'floor' require that the turtle know where it is located on the floor.  There is no concept of that 'current location' in the posted code.

Comment: The use of 'getchar()' depends somewhat on: is there any other characters in the input file other than U,D,R,L,F?  for instance newlines?

Comment: the movement code blocks are not taking into consideration the limits of the 'floor' .   Generally, with a mouse, forward motion is where ever the mouse is currently pointed.  so actions like turnleft|right and motion forward are all related to the current direction the mouse is facing.  In GPS terminology: mouse movements are `track up` not `north up`

Comment: I'm starting to realize now that I really need to improve my coding knowledge, and I appreciate your help. There isn't any other characters, which would indicate that that solution wouldn't work. My code seems to work when using your intial idea of `while(fscanf(file,"%c", &command) == 1)` At least I think that's what you meant? I get an output but I do think I need to re-do the turns. Although all they are doing is changing the direction in which the turtle is facing, is that not when they are doing?

Comment: I might suggest: rather than working with some arbitrary sized array `commands[]` it would be much more flexible to, in a loop,*read one command, act on that command, back to top of loop*

Comment: I agree that would be a better method, but according to the assignment i've received we have to store the commands into an array.

Comment: which way the turtle (sorry about calling it a mouse) is facing has nothing to do with the boundaries of the `floor` but has a massive impact on how the x,y coordinates are modified in handling the `F` command.  Note: a turn does not care if the 'pen' is up or down, only the 'F' command cares

Comment: Now that I look at it I can't really see whats wrong with my turnLeft/turnRight functions. They are taking the current direction and rotating the turtle 90 degrees clockwise/counterclockwise. Is this not an effective way? if not what would be a better way? Sorry for all the questions, i've only been coding C for 2/3 weeks and we've been thrown in the deep end here with this assignment.. You don't even know how much I appreciate your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at your `while` loop in `execCommands()`. You use the first command twice, and not the last. Your code (showing only relevant parts) is:

```
int i = 0;
...

cmd = commands[i];

while ( ncmds-- ) {
    switch ( cmd ) {
       ...
    }
    cmd = commands[i++];
}
```

`ncmds` is the number of commands (function argument), which decrements counting the number of commands read. You use `i` to count from 0 up to `ncmds`.  But look where you modify `i`. The first time you get to `cmd = commands[i++]` at the end, this stores the same value in `cmd` as it had from the initialization `cmd = commands[i]`.  So this first command is used twice, and you only use `ncmds` in total, so the last is excluded.  If `P` is the last command of the input file (I might want to print the result at the end), it will not be executed.

You can simply replace `i++` with `++i`.  But a `for` loop might be more readable:

```
int i;
...

for ( i=0; i<ncmds; i++ ) {
    switch ( commands[i] ) {
       ...
    }
}
```

Notice that you don't even need the `cmd` variable since you don't refer to it in any of the `switch` cases.

---

Are you sure you're even reading the commands correctly?  You do something similar in `readCommands()`:

```
fscanf(file,"%c", &command);
while(!feof(file)){
    fscanf(file,"%c", &command);
    for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++){
        counter++;
        commands[i]= command;
    }
}
```

You read one `char` into `command`, then at the beginning of the loop, you read another `char` into `command`, without doing anything with the first.  I'm not even sure what that `for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++)` is for. It looks like it would just fill every space in the `commands` buffer with the same command, then this gets repeated with the next command, etc.  This is not what you want.  You might want to rethink your strategy here.

Comment: I appreciate the help! This was code that was included in the assignment by the professor, never thought of looking there for the error..

Comment: It is a cruel professor that gives broken code not labelled as broken. But that is also a technique to get students to read and understand code.  If they thought it worked, they wouldn't bother reading it, just as you did.